# should PAX be in Flighth Dimension or Fact Sales table?

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, powerpivot, star-schema

I need to build a data mart using power pivot for a duty free shop at Airport.
Sales manager is analying sales data using by flight number and by PAX, number of people per flight.
So, I don't know where to put PAX. In DimFlight or FactSales. It is addative, right?
Please explain me why and how should I put PAX into which table. DimFlight may includes airline, flignt_no, date, PAX. A flight may also land the airport more than once a day.

Comment: the question looks awfully similar to a quiz / interview question

Comment: sorry for my bad English writing.

Comment: FYI: Flight would be considered a measurable event.  Date should not be in the flight dimension.  You'd be better served create a DimRoute, DimAirline, DimPlane, DimDate and having a FactFlight that references those dimensions.  If you make a DimFlight having a record for every flight, you'll likely end up with a 1=1 match between your fact and dim.  That is generally an indicator that you have a design problem.

Answer (score 1):

PAX is a fact describing a measureable value of a specific flight event.  It should be in the fact table, not in the flight dimension.  I would expect total capacity to be an attribute of the plane dimension associated to the flight event.  (Flight number would likely be a degenerate dimension as it doesn't really own any attributes.)  However, the PAX itself should be a measure in the fact table.

You can generate a junk dimension that has the banding mentioned by @Luis Leal to do some capacity analytics.  You can even create a numbers dimension with an attribute for each group level so you can do more detailed banding.  For example, an attribute for 1s, 10s, 100s, 1000s, etc.  You can also calculate the filled capacity of the flight and point to the numbers dimension so you can group flights by 80% full, 90% full etc.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing stops you from modeling it as both dimension and measure, so you can store it both on a dimension table and as a measure on a fact table. If you store it as a measure on the fact table, you can perform several analysis by the other possible dimensions, get insights as averages, max, min, total by x or y dimension, which would be very difficult if you store it only on the dimension table.

On the other hand,storing it in the dimension table enables additional "perspectives" of analysis, for example a common approach is to store in the dimensional table "interval" columns with values like:
from 1 to 1000 pax, from 1001 to 2000. This column calculated at ETL time depending on the value of the PAX. So why not use both?